# Using asteriks in robots.txt

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt

Can spiders crawl the sites if there are no asterisks used on the robots.txt?

For example:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: .*/ping/.*
```

then

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /ping/
```

Please can someone confirm this, many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @w3dk said you can't use dot asterisk (.*) in robots.txt with directory, it will probably gives you an error or you will not going to accomplish that you want.

.dot prefix used to block specific kind of file, like this.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: *.pdf
```

This will block all pdf files to crawl in your website. No matter it is in root level or in sub folder.

Your second robots.txt clarification.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /ping/
```

Here all polite bots including Googlebot, MSNBot, Yandexbot allowed to crawl your all directory except /ping/ directory, but your /ping/ directory should be placed in root level, otherwise it won't work.

```
First example - www.example.com/ping/ 
Second example (This won't work) - www.example.com/sub/ping/
```

Comment: Note that the pattern the OP used is `.*` (regex style, dot-asterisk) - this is probably in error. The dot here is a literal dot, not _any character_. (Also note that robots.txt is _prefix matching_, so any wildcard `*` at the end of the URL-path is superfluous.)

Comment: Thanks w3dk for clarification. I am going to change my answer.